# Descending numbers from the middle of a matrix in Java

Tags: java, matrix, user-input

I have a problem and not idea how to solve it. 
My program should read three input numbers :

- length of array
- highest number
- decreasing rate

[image: 1]

In this example, the length of the array is 9, highest number is 100 and decreasing rate is 15 (this means that numbers are decreasing by a rate of 15 (100 - 15 = 85, 85 - 15 = 70, ...). Also, the numbers can't go past 0 - they can't be negative.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: So where's the problem? What did you try so far and where did you get stuck? If you have a look at the example you should be able to spot a pattern so formulating an algorithm shouldn't be that hard (and I guess this is some sort of homework so it should be _you_ who comes up with the algorithm).

Comment: And also, what should your program do with these 3 numbers?

Comment: I am guessing u r new to java, use loops and build ur own logic...it will help u in future

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the number in the center is the highest number `H`, the number at the position `(r, c)` is computed by multiplying [*Manhattan Distance*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taxicab_geometry) from the center to `(r, c)`, and multiplying it by the decrease rate.

You can use this observation to compute a number at any spot in the matrix: add absolute differences in both coordinates together, multiply by the rate of decrease, subtract from the highest number, and limit with zero to ensure that the number does not become negative.

Comment: How could you even understand the problem statement with very less statements in the question ??. Nice work.

Comment: Thank you very much and I'm so sorry for the lack of information. Thanks again!